# Does empty LONGTEXT string takes 4GB of disc space?

Tags: mysql

I've been reading about disc usage/space for different strings, it says that `LONGTEXT` takes `4GB`.

Is that disk space declared for `FULLY FILLED column` or `JUST CREATED (Empty)`

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: `L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32`

> Variable-length string types are stored using a length prefix plus
>   data. The length prefix requires from one to four bytes depending on
>   the data type, and the value of the prefix is L (the byte length of
>   the string). For example, storage for a MEDIUMTEXT value requires L
>   bytes to store the value plus three bytes to store the length of the
>   value.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings

Comment: Are you saying an empty/null longtext field grabs all this disk space?

Comment: Lol, no. It takes L + 4 bytes where L is the byte length of the string. An empty String (not null) should be about 1 byte + 4 bytes, if I'm not mistaken.